# How to register Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

My asp.net c# webforms site use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 
the project work fine local when i publish it to the server i get this message

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Both developer computer and server are 64 bit

I try to put dll on bin folder in server - dosent work.

Comment: Just install Office on the server. This libs causes more problems than it solves. It's always better to use an external library to work with docs/docsx

Comment: can i use any version of office? i dont want to bye license to the web server

Comment: Even if you installed Office including the interop; pretty sure it is a violation of the User Software Agreement to use such software on a Server environment.  Ah found it: _"[Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)"_

Comment: So the only thing is use 3rd party library?

Comment: @eyalb The *best* thing is using a 3rd party library. [Office Interop does not work well on servers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). Why not try [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/)? No strange COM errors, fully managed (.NET library) etc.